How to deal with zeros when using NBEATS to forcast demand?
So, I'm doing forecasting demand for a hotel using NBEATS, which is hierarchically organized. However, I'm facing an issue with the time series data at the bottom (room numbers), as they're filled with zeros, and I'm unsure how to address this. I've managed to capture the main trend, but it struggles with handling peaks effectively. I've come across the Croston model, but I'm not looking for an average; rather, I want to predict the number of people who will want a particular room on a given day. While I have ideas for adding more layers, I'm hesitant as it might complicate matters further. One concept I've considered is to use XGBoost after making predictions with NBEATS, which could help in predicting spikes and other nuances.




I've come across the Croston model, but I'm not looking for an average; rather, I want to predict the number of people who will want a particular room on a given day.

At very granular levels (here: room/day), demands often turn into intermittent-time-series. Forecasting these is hard, and intermittent series is where the differences between different point forecasts becomes important, and visible. If your time series is 0/1 valued, i.e., whether a room is occupied or not, the expectation forecast is a number that can be interpreted as a probability, and any quantile forecast will be either 0 or 1.
It sounds like you want a hard 0/1 forecast for whether a given room will be occupied on a given day. This is very hard indeed. Suppose you have a 50% chance that a room is occupied on any given day, what hard forecast would you use? Any series of 0/1 forecasts will most likely be quite off, no matter what you do. Of course, you will likely have differential probabilities, with higher occupancy probabilities on some days than on others - but your expectation forecasts will take care of these.
This is actually a "time series case of classification", and I would argue that as for classification, you would be much better off using that fractional forecast, see these previous threads:

Classification probability threshold
Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?
Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?

For one, you can meaningfully aggregate probabilistic forecasts, and at the end of the day, you are almost certainly not interested in the occupancy of a specific room, but in total occupancy at an entire location.
Note that I cast the discussion above in terms of a 0/1 occupancy time series, but it immediately transfers to time series of the total number of people in any given room.
We have some resources on forecasting in this tag: Resources/books for project on forecasting models. Most of the textbooks etc. contain entire chapters on intermittent demand forecasting. In addition, the tag wiki for intermittent time series has a few pointers.
